# Does GORM support attibutes of many to many relationships?

Tags: go, go-gorm

Using the gorm.io library, how would I implement a `many to many` relationship, where the relationship itself has attributes?

### Example:

[image]

Without the attribute I would do it something like this, but I can't find a solution to my Problem in the GORM docs.

```golang
type Recipe struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name string
    Ingredients []Ingredient `gorm:"many2many"`
}

type Ingredient struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name string
}
```

Comment: https://gorm.io/docs/many_to_many.html#Customize-JoinTable